# Did Hinata really confess to Naruto?

Tags: naruto

When Naruto and Hinata were fighting Pain in Konoha, did Naruto hear Hinata's confession or was it just in Hinata's mind?

Comment: Where and when?

Comment: When Naruto fought Pain in Konoha Village.

Comment: @Oded important question ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look up in Manga chapter 437, page 12, where Hinata has her own Crowning Moment Of Awesome.

Yes he did ;)

Comment: I couldn't determine it though as Naruto has that dumb look on his face. :/

Comment: it's somewhat better in the anime. they make clear that he had not the slightest clue ...

Comment: Which is why I had no clue is Naruto actually heard her confessing and made me speculate that it's all in Hinata's mind.

Comment: @infiniteBladeWorks in The Last: Naruto the Movie when Naruto is in that Genjutsu, he is seeing the past. In a flashback he sees that moment, where he is on the ground and Hinata is protecting him, and hears Hinata confessing her love for him.